# how do i find on what place a certain letter is in a sentence? (c programming)

Tags: c, arrays, text, warnings, editing

I'm trying to find to find which position a number has in a sentence in c. I'm kinda new to programming and i don't know why my code isn't working.

i keep getting this warning but i have no clue what it means *(english isn't my first language)*:

passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] Main.c  /TweeIntegers   line 20 C/C++ Problem

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i, y;
    char x;

    char text1[] = "een stuk text";
    char text2[] = "k";

    for ( i = 0; i < strlen(text1); i++ )
    {
        x = text1[i];
        y = strcmp( x, text2 )
    }

    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable `x` is a single `char`, the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function compares *strings* (i.e. arrays of zero-terminated characters).

Comment: You are passing a `char` (ie an integer) to a function that takes in two `char *` (ie strings)

Comment: for the general case (looking for a sub-string), try [`strstr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr)

Comment: [sample of find first occurrence](https://ideone.com/6U2ptI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are only looking for a char and the first position then you can use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int i;

  char text1[] = "een stuk text";
  char charYouLookFor = 'k';

  for ( i = 0; i < strlen(text1); i++ )
  {
    if (text1[i] == charYouLookFor)
       break;
  }

  printf("%d", i);

  return 0;
}
```

If you are looking for the position of a text in a text or for the second position of the char the code needs to be more complex.

Comment: `char charYouLookFor = "k";` <- fail... (this assigns the integer value of the pointer to your string literal `"k"`, converted to a `char`, to your variable)

Answer (score 1):

strcspn will search for list of characters and return the index of the first match. In this case the list is only the letter `k`. In case of no match found it returns the length of the string searched.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int y = 0;
    char text1[] = "een stuk text";
    char text2[] = "k";

    y = strcspn ( text1, text2);

    printf("%d", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a single character with a string, but `strcmp()` compares two strings. You can solve this by dropping the whole loop and simply use `strchr()` to locate the character. `strstr(text1, text2)` would have worked as well, since text2 is a string (properly null-terminated).

Pre-made search functions in string.h:

- `strchr()` finds a single character inside a string.
- `strstr()` finds a sub-string inside another string.
- `strpbrk()` finds any character from a list of specified characters inside another string.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `strcmp()` to compare whole strings, which is not what you're trying to do.

To locate a single character in a string, just use [`strchr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr). No need to loop yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i, y;
    char x;

    const char text[] = "een stuk text";
    char letter = 'k';

    const char * const found = strchr(text, letter);
    if(found != 0)
      printf("%d\n", (int) (found - text));

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
7
```

Which is correct, it's the 8th letter.